# error when connecting PostgreSql with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

i trying to connect nodejs with postgreSql for the backend of my project and

im getting this error: testConnection.jsx:11 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

this is my server code

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000; // Change the port as needed

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

 //TestConnection 
 app.get('/api/TestConnection', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.json({ message: 'Connected to backend successfully!' });
});

// PostgreSQL database connection
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'GamingWorld',
  password: 'postgres',
  port: 5432,
});

// Example API endpoint for user registration
app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // Hash the password before storing in the database
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    // Insert user into the database
    const query = 'INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)';
    await pool.query(query, [username, email, hashedPassword]);

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during user registration:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred' });
  }
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

i also write a component to check the respone from the server

```
'import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function TestConnection() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/TestConnection')  
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response); // Log the entire response object
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => setMessage(data.message))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Connection Test</h2>
      <p>Server response: {message}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TestConnection;
```

thank you for helping.

i try to put a proxy in packge-lock.json and it didnt help

Comment: Please add more details of the error you are getting.

Comment: I don't see `/api/TestConnection` such an API in your server code.

Comment: i have it in line 12